# Change woocommerce product attributes url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, woocommerce, attributes

I 'd like to have url like http://wp-domain.com/custom-product where custom-product will request http://wp-domain.com/pa_product-type/custom

Attributes=product-type, value=custom and some product-category and sub-category can have this attributes. So http://wp-domain.com/custom-product will return all product that have attributes custom.

I have tried some test using .htaccess like :

RewriteRule   ^custom-product$  /pa_product-type/custom [L]

but never success. what's wrong? 
Appreciate and great thank for your help

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you try to rephrase it and provide more detail?

Answer (score 1):

You can change Woocommerce Product category URL from WordPress -> Settings -> Permalinks. Please refer [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/permalinks/)

Comment: Hi thank for your help. But honestly I am confused how to change url for some attributes (product-type) using wordpress Permalink Setting. Will you give some example?